# Sql won't get values WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, json

Okay, so I'm trying to create an app for iOS.

My problem is that, what I think, when using JSON and combine it with sql, somehow it does not work.

So this is my code

```
<?php
$user='Admin';
echo $user;


    $host='HOST';
    $user='USER';
    $password='PASSWORD';



    $connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);

    if(!$connection){
        die('Connection Failed');
    }
    else{
        $dbconnect = @mysql_select_db('DATABASE', $connection);

        if(!$dbconnect){
            die('Could not connect to Database');
        }
        else{
            $query = "SELECT * FROM AppLogin WHERE Username = '".$user."' ";
            $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

            $records= array();

            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
                $records[] = $r;
            }

            echo json_encode($records);
        }
    }
?>
```

The output I get is

Admin[]

If I do it like this

```
<?php


        $host='HOST';
        $user='USER';
        $password='PASSWORD';



        $connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);

        if(!$connection){
            die('Connection Failed');
        }
        else{
            $dbconnect = @mysql_select_db('DATABASE', $connection);

            if(!$dbconnect){
                die('Could not connect to Database');
            }
            else{
                $query = "SELECT * FROM AppLogin WHERE Username = 'Admin' ";
                $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

                $records= array();

                while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
                    $records[] = $r;
                }

                echo json_encode($records);
            }
        }
    ?>
```

I get the output I want:

[{"Username":"Admin","Password":"Password"}]

Why is the sql not working when I'm using WHERE = '".$value."'

Albin

Comment: `$user='Admin';` and `$user='USER';`. The second one is overwriting the other.

Comment: Are you sure `$user` is a valid user and that the query shall return something with it?

Comment: What @Fred-ii- is pointing out is that you used the same variable name (`$user`) for the user name in the SQL query and the user name you use to connect to the database in `mysql_connect()`. Also please note that *mysql IS DEPRECATED AND NOT SECURE. USE mysqli or PDO*

Comment: Anyhow @Fred-ii- is right, in the first script you're overwriting `$user` value

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM AppLogin WHERE Username ='$user' "; Try this one.

Comment: ... Of course it did not work. Like you said @Fred-ii , $user in the begining needs to have a different name then $user for the connection to DB. I tried rename it and now it works. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: @HerrJulle You're welcome and I've posted an answer for it that you can choose to close the question with if you wish. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36811725/ This informs that the solution to the question was found. *Cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments:

> *"$user='Admin'; and $user='USER';. The second one is overwriting the other."*

Therefore, you need to rename one of those.

Plus, you should really switch to [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) or [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) if your server supports them, as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for the downvote. It's a change from seeing green all the time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$query = "SELECT * FROM AppLogin WHERE Username = '$user' ";`